# When I run the code I get an error "Cannot find tables 0"

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
Public Shared Function JMPDetails(ByVal frht As Double, ByVal toht As Double, ByVal Type As Integer) As DataTable
            Dim ds As New DataSet()
            Dim da As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter = rwfGen.Connection.Adapter
            Try
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@frht", SqlDbType.BigInt, 8).Value = frht
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@toht", SqlDbType.BigInt, 8).Value = toht
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = Type
                da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "mm_sp_SpectroQuery"
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 3600
                da.Fill(ds)
                JMPDetails = ds.Tables(0)
            Catch exp As Exception
                Throw New Exception(exp.Message)
            Finally
                da.Dispose()
                ds.Dispose()
            End Try
        End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems dataset has not received any value from your database. check your store procedure, parameter values whether they are satisfying the condition to get the result.
And in code it is always good to check for any exception. Check with the following:

Vb.Net:

```
   If (ds.Tables.Count > 0) Then                
      If (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then
        'do your staff
        JMPDetails = ds.Tables(0)
      End If
    End If
```

C#:

```
if(ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{
  if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
  {
    // do your staff
    JMPDetails = ds.Tables[0]
  }
}
```

Comment: stored procedure and parameter are all right still it's giving the error

Comment: please try to check the output of store procedure in a sql query editor. And see if data is coming or not with the query